# Kubernetes automatic shutdown after some idle time

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Does kubernetes or Helm support shut down the pods if it is idle for more than a given threshold time?

This would be very useful in the development environment, to provide room for other processes to consume it and save cost.

Comment: A [horizontal pod autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-custom-metrics) was designed to solve that problem, so long as your Pods are able to surface the metric that you would use to know which ones to kill. It may be possible to do time-math from `metadata.creationTimestamp` but I don't know off-hand the syntax to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kubernetes is featured with the ability to autoscale your application in a cluster. Literally, it means that Kubernetes can start additional pods when the load is increasing and terminate excessive pods when the load is decreasing.

It is possible to downscale the application to zero pods, but, in this case, you will have a delay serving the first request while the pod is starting.

This functionality relies on performance metrics provided by [Heapster](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster) application, that must be run in the cluster. From the practical side, it means that autoscaling doesn't happen instantly, because it takes some time to performance metrics reach the configured threshold.

The mentioned Kubernetes feature called HPA(horizontal pod autoscale) is described in this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/).

In case you are running your cluster on GCP or GKE, you are able to go further and automatically start additional nodes for your cluster when you need more computing capacity and shut down nodes when they are not running application pods anymore.

More information about this functionality can be found following the [link](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/07/autoscaling-in-kubernetes/).

If you decide to give it a try, you might find this information useful:

- [Creating a Container cluster in GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-container-cluster#create_a_cluster_with_autoscaling)
- [70% cheaper Kubernetes cluster on AWS](https://carlosbecker.com/posts/k8s-sandbox-costs/)
- [How to build a Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler using custom metrics](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-scaler/)

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/heapster repository are archived

Comment: It was substituted by https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question